# Website closes automatically after loading in iPhone's safari browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, apache

I developed a website in `PHP` and it is working fine in desktop browsers and browsers in android. When I try to access it using safari on an iPhone or even when i type the URL on the google search bar on an android, the website loads and then just closes(on android) or redirects to the launch page of safari(on iPhone).

Here's the Url to the [Website](https://nashikchicken.com).

Can it be any error in JavaScript?
It sometimes loads perfectly fine and sometimes doesn't.Once the tab of google chrome in desktop also closed automatically.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: (Errors that are worth fixing anyway: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fnashikchicken.com%2F)

Comment: Can please share the purpose of line #319 in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of window.close you use in line 319.
I checked in internet explorer where tab get closed. It might be because of version of safari you are using.Modern browsers do not close tab through script.

Comment: yes that was the problem in my code. Thank you

Comment: that was actually a silly mistake from my side.  :p